# Reflection floor on openGl ES 2.0

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es

How can I make reflection floor in OpenGl ES 2.0 in which I'll see reflections of objects: spheres, cubes, etc. Everything that I saw was OpenGL samples for desktop.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, i tried make reflection floor using stencil buffer, but don't have results

Comment: To get a good answer, it helps to show some code and ask specific questions. This questions is a little too wide for SO. Try breaking it down!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflections are typically done with a technique called render to texture.  You render your initial scene to an FBO with an attached texture, then use that texture to render the reflection image onto a quad in the final scene.  I think this article with help:

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Render_to_Texture_with_OpenGL_ES